# Squid TCP_DENIED/403 with internal ERROR Page

Tags: squid

I have a plain installation of new Squid and Apache2. Both are with default configuration. The Server (ubunut 18.04) is registered on internal DNS Server like: srv1.foo.bar.

If some one is not allowed to get access to the internet squid displays the internal Error Message Page but without die Squid logo. I get the following Error Message in Log File:

`TCP_DENIED/403 4187 GET http://srv1.foo.bar:3128/squid-internal-static/icons/SN.png - HIER_NONE/- text/html`

The only thing to display the logo was remark http_access deny all. my configuration: Squid Cache: Version 3.5.27

 `acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 3128
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl localnet src 192.168.168.0/24
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320`

Hope someone can help me. wrbrgds AxelF